# How to create a wireless-to-ethernet router?

Tags: debian, networking, routing, bridge

I have a Debian machine, which I want to turn into a router.

It will connect via wireless to a access-point, where it will get an IP.

To its ethernet port, other machines will be connected. It will run udhcpd to give machines connected to the ethernet port, their IP´s.

This all works so far, including the routing tables I have setup.

The problem is, that connected to the access-point is another machine. It broadcasts udp packets and these packets are not routed to the machines that are connected to the ethernet port on my router. How do I resolve this?

Bridging the wlan0 and eth0 ports?

Comment: Bridging should work, but you lose routing on your machine since the bridge is one layer under IP.  With a bridge, the other hosts will effectively be on the same wireless network as the other wireless clients.  If this is not what you want, and you need a firewall, you may need to run dhcpd on the machine and use it as a router instead of a bridge.